# How to establish cross domain connection if the server doesn't send a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to establish a cross domain connection with a server I dont have access with. Its getting below exception

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-     Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can anyone help me how to establish cross domain connection if the server doesn't send a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header echoing back the same origin that was sent or *.

Comment: Have you tried Jsonp ? I found it to be a good solution if you mainly need to get things from that server and not post much data. Also, what is the technology of your server ?

Comment: I tried adding Jsonp also. Its not working. I edited my question.